# iOS webapp external link jumps to homescreen

Tags: ios, web-applications

I created a simple 2 page webapp (for testing) when I install this to the home screen of an iOS device. I can navigate from the home page to page 2 (where a link to a movie (mp4) is located).

When I open the link (opens in a new window which will cause a new instance of safari with the movie).

So far so good.

But when I close the movie. I see that the webapp changed to the home page again which should have stayed on page 2.

In short: 
1. WebApp installed to homepage on iOS device (http://ctmri.masterapp2.nl/test/) 
2. Opened WebApp (homepage)
3. Clicked link to Page 2 (page 2 gets shown)
4. Clicked on movie link (movie opens in new safari instance ... OK)
5. Closed movie and the WebApp has navigated back to the **Homepage**.

Can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The webapp is loaded again. Try it with a single file and an iframe. Save the iframe url using cookies or localStorage

Comment: The link on the second page in external so you browse away from the webapp. Why would the page then reload?

Comment: The webapp reloads everytime it opens. When you move away its temporarily closed. Dont know why apple is doing this